# 手動で設定した ElasticBeanstalk の設定を .elasticbeanstalk の形式にしたい

Tags: aws, aws-elasticbeanstalk

Elasticbeanstalk で、 docker での deploy にあたって、 GUI (aws web console) から作成し、その後ひとまず手動オペレーションで試行錯誤した結果、動くようになった Environment があります。

しかし、この環境を Infrastructure as Code したくなった場合には、この形式ではいろいろ辛いと思っています。具体的には、 `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml` の形式に、手動で行った設定を反映することが必要だろうなと思うのですが、さらにここから config.yml に対して試行錯誤するのはちょっと辛いです。

質問:

- 手動で web console の上から設定された Elasticbeanstalk Environment に対して、その設定を `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml` の形式に変換するツール・コマンドなどありますでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ElasticBeanstalk は、 Application に対して Environment を複数作成できます。 Environment は webconsole や aws-cli から操作を行って、もろもろの変更を加えることができます。

Environment の設定は、 Saved Configuration によって、その設定自体を保存できます。保存された設定を、 Environment に適用したり、保存された設定から Environment を新たに作り直したりできます。また、この Saved Configuration はファイル形式で export もできる様子です。

自分が欲しかったものは、この Saved Configuration の様子です。